# how would I create a tar without using sudo?

Tags: backup, tar

If I tar my /home/username and create the .tar file in /home/username, then I get an error of the sort `. file changed as we read it` probably because the directory file itself is changing due to the creation of the .tar file.  Of course I could have the file created one level up in /home but that would require sudo or a login.  I want to archive and restore without sudo and a re-login.

I don't want to nest the .tar file deep somewhere in /home/username that is less convenient and I suspect that might not even solve the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to create file in /tmp directory.

Comment: @brunopereira81 points out that people should pay attention to what /tmp is.  "tmp" means temporary so copy it to something like a DVD.

Comment: @brunopereira81 points out /tmp is not private.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `--exclude=` flag to create one archive that ignores a directory were you are writing your backup to.

Make a `/home/<username>/Backups` folder.

Try it like this (replace any other extra options and the file you want to create):
`tar <extra options> /home/<username>/Backups/yourhomefolderbackup.tar.gz --exclude=/home/<username>/Backups/ /home/<username>/`

This way you can save your backups, make new ones, remove them, burn them without the worry that if you reboot your machine your previous backups are deleted (that will happen if you are saving them to /tmp, once you reboot your backups are gone!).

Also you should use the `--exclude=` to exclude the `/home/<username>/.local/share/trash` folder (or where is your `.trash` folder at.   **EDIT:**   In Ubuntu its located at `/home/<username>/.trash`) from the archive you are creating or your trash will be added to the backup you are creating. Just add another `--exclude=/home/<username>/.trash` after the first `--exclude=` and that is all!

Hf, gl ;)

Comment: That's not what was said ;) You are creating and archive under your home that contains your home files and directories **except** you archive file.

Comment: Saw a fault, fixed it.

Comment: I also like this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I know. There is always 100 ways of frying an egg, not all of them will make good fried eggs! ;) (included reasons why you should save to /home backup folder and not to /tmp, the /tmp version is still valid ofc)

Comment: Added instructions to remove your `.trash` folder so it doesn't show (is added) on your backup archive.

Comment: Any file going to /tmp and /home/<user>/backups is not really backed up because it's still on moving media.  Even a DVD made with the "add more files later" option sounds kind of unsafe.

Comment: True, but at least you keep it more time then a on the /tmp folder.  You are sure that if you reboot it wont go away automatic!

Comment: And well, a backup is still a backup, even if its on the same media, the only thing that this solution does better is to keep that backup on a "safer" forlder. 1) It wont go away with a reboot, 2) other user will not be able to read your files because you saved them on your home folder and not on /tmp.